# Is ISO-8859-1 encoding binary-safe in Java?

Tags: java, character-encoding

If I read a binary stream into a String using an ISO-8859-1 encoding, and subsequently convert it back to a binary stream, would I always get exactly the same bytes? And if not, when would I not get the same bytes?

```
public byte[] toStringAndBack(byte[] binaryData) throws Exception {
    String s = new String(binaryData, "ISO-8859-1");
    return s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
}
```

=== EDIT ===

Test:

```
    byte[] d = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, (byte)128, (byte)129, (byte)130}; // some not defined values
    byte[] dd = toStringAndBack(d);
    for (byte b : dd)
        System.out.print((b&0xFF) + " ");
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 128 129 130
```

So, even not defined bytes seem to be converted properly.

Comment: I would guess it is **not safe**. ISO-8859 is a text encoding, and you cannot arbitrarily convert any binary data from/to it. Case in point: not all byte codes are [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout).

Comment: ^^ Exactly my thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [constructor you're using](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.lang.String-) says:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the given charset is unspecified.

So in theory it could fail for any value ISO-8859-1 doesn't assign characters to, such as 0-31 and 128-160.

That means even if it works on a given JVM's `String` implementation (or `Charset` implementation for ISO-8859-1), you cannot rely on it working on another JVM's `String`/`Charset` implementation (whether that's just a different dot-rev of a JVM from the same vendor, or a different vendor's JVM).

Comment: Hmm, this constructor is there since 1997, and the chance of it suddenly working differently is almost nonexistent, as it is way too risky for a JRE vendor to change it. So for quick-and-dirty code this can be acceptable. But thanks for finding the explanation for the behavior. I understand this can't be relied upon.

Comment: @rustyx: Yeah, if you're only running on a single vendor's JVM implementation and that implementation is mature, I suspect it won't suddenly change. But in theory there are multiple JVMs. (The only two I know of both use Sun's sources for the JDK classes, though, I believe.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's test it:

```
// all possible bytes
byte[] bin = new byte[256];
for (int i=0; i<bin.length; i++)
    bin[i] = (byte)i;

// convert to string
String s = new String(bin, "ISO-8859-1");
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
    if (s.charAt(i) != i)
        System.out.println(i + " s[i]=" + s.charAt(i));
}

// convert back to byte[]
byte[] bout = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
for (int i=0; i<bin.length; i++)
{
    if (bin[i] != bout[i])
        System.out.println(i + " in=" + bin[i] + " bout=" + bout[i]);
}

System.out.println("done");
```

It prints only `done`.

Therefore at least for the current ISO-8859-1 implementation the operations are binary safe as defined in the question.

EDIT:
the current implementation is `sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1`.
Looking at the source it only checks if a char is < 256 to decide if it can be encoded.

Comment: *"...at least for the current ISO-8859-1 implementation..."* <== Big big big caveat there! If it's documented not to work (as it appears to be), that means it can break between dot releases of the JDK classes (or work on Oracle's but not on a third-party JDK class implementation), etc.